# In J2ME, How to set Header information with HttpConnection?

Tags: java-me, midp, j2mepolish, midp-2.0

I have used HttpConnection in J2ME for communication between server. I want to send some data to server with http header. Can anybody tel me how to set header information with HttpConnection. Any example.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

From http://www.j2mesalsa.com/elearning/networking.html :

> Set Header Information
>
> To set request header properties use setRequestProperty(String key, String value).

Example:

`setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-1.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0" )`

Hope it helps.